# How to add extra fields like radio,checkbox in custom module in magento 2 admin?

Tags: magento2

How to add extra fields in cusotm module and get the config based on frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Use you can use this one as a start.
https://www.mage-world.com/blog/grid-and-form-in-magento-2-admin-panel-part-2.html

```
//for checkbox
$fieldset->addField(
            'status',
            'checkbox',
            [
                'name'      => 'status',
                'label'     => __('Status'),
                'required'     => true
            ]
        );
//for radio button
$fieldset->addField(
            'gender',
            'radio',
            [
                'name'      => 'gender',
                'label'     => __('Male'),
                'required'     => true
            ]
        );

$fieldset->addField(
            'gender',
            'radio',
            [
                'name'      => 'gender',
                'label'     => __('Female'),
                'required'     => true
            ]
        );
```

Hope it helps.